# Program creates an infinite number of copies of itself

Tags: java, constructor, awt, infinite-loop

I am writing a program for my java class that displays a binary tree. However one of the problems I'm running into is that the program creates an infinite number of copies of itself when it's first executed. I'm fairly sure I know where the problem is, I just have no idea how to fix it. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

I think the problem is at the end of this constructor:

```
public Window_Controller() throws HeadlessException {

            addMouseListener(this);
        addWindowListener(close);

        setTitle("Binary Trees - Alpha Stage");
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setLocation(40, 0);
        setVisible(true);

        incrementButton = new Button("+1", Color.white, deLoc - 47, y, 45);
        decrementButton = new Button("-1", Color.white, deLoc, y, 45);
        fullButton = new Button("Full Binary Tree", Color.cyan, x, y, 110);
        completeButton = new Button("Complete Binary Tree", Color.green, x + 130, y, 150);
        // I think this is the problem
        fullTree = new Full_Binary_Tree();
    }
```

Because this class extends the Window_Controller class:

```
public class Full_Binary_Tree extends Window_Controller
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -3599016597017756766L;

    BinaryNode rootNode;
    BinaryNode current;
    BinaryNode leftNode;
    BinaryNode rightNode;

    /**
     * @throws HeadlessException
     */
    public Full_Binary_Tree() throws HeadlessException
    {

    }

    public void add(int value)
    {
        BinaryNode aNode = new BinaryNode(value);
        aNode.setLeftNode(rootNode);
        rootNode = aNode;
        current = rootNode;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        if(rootNode.getRightNode() == null) {
            g2d.drawLine(rootNode.getX() + 25, rootNode.getY() + 25, rootNode.getX() + 65, rootNode.getY() + 87);
            g2d.setColor(nullColor);
            g2d.setFont(nullFont);
            g2d.drawString("NULL", rootNode.getX() + 60, rootNode.getY() + 100);
            g2d.setFont(defaultFont);
            g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        }

        if(rootNode.getLeftNode() == null) {
            g2d.drawLine(rootNode.getX() + 25, rootNode.getY() + 25, rootNode.getX() - 15, rootNode.getY() + 87);
            g2d.setColor(nullColor);
            g2d.setFont(nullFont);
            g2d.drawString("NULL", rootNode.getX() - 42, rootNode.getY() + 100);
            g2d.setFont(defaultFont);
            g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        }

        if(current != null) {
            current.paint(g2d);
        }



    }
}
```

I think what's happening is when the `main()` method calls the constructor and it reaches that line it calls the constructor in Full_Binary_Tree, which will call the constructor for the Window_Constructor class. Of course I could be wrong and the problem is completely unrelated to this.

Comment: You're correct - recursive object instantiation. Why do you even need the `Window_Controller` class?

Comment: Yes that is the problem..But why are you calling `fullTree = new Full_Binary_Tree();` within `Window_Controller()` constructor? Why not create a separate method within `Window_Controller` class where you create the object of `FullTree` and call that method via the object of `Window_Controller` in your program ?

Comment: @home I'm using the `Window_Controller` class to create the window and buttons on it, the `Full_Binary_Tree` class handles the creation of the binary tree. @VishalK I'll try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating `Full_Binary_Tree` object within `Window_Controller` constructor you should create separate method within `Window_Controller` class where you create the `Full_Binary_Tree` object. For example your code should be something like this:

```
public class Window_Controller
{
....
 public Window_Controller() throws HeadlessException {

            addMouseListener(this);
        addWindowListener(close);

        setTitle("Binary Trees - Alpha Stage");
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setLocation(40, 0);
        setVisible(true);

        incrementButton = new Button("+1", Color.white, deLoc - 47, y, 45);
        decrementButton = new Button("-1", Color.white, deLoc, y, 45);
        fullButton = new Button("Full Binary Tree", Color.cyan, x, y, 110);
        completeButton = new Button("Complete Binary Tree", Color.green, x + 130, y, 150);
        // I think this is the problem
        //fullTree = new Full_Binary_Tree();//Don't create object of Full_Binary_Tree here.
    }
  public synchronized void createFullBinaryTreeInstance()
  {
    if (fullTree == null)
    fullTree = new Full_Binary_Tree();
  }
}
```

Now, When you are creating `Window_Controller` object call `createFullBinaryTreeInstance()` method explicity after the creation of object . Like:

```
Window_Controller wController = new Window_Controller();
wController.createFullBinaryTreeInstance();
```

Comment: I could also use this to create a tree when a button is pressed with a method like this: `private void fullAction(){ createFullBinaryTreeInstance(); }` right?

Comment: Yes, You could but You must call it using the instance of `Window_Controller` class. Like `private void fullAction(){ wController.createFullBinaryTreeInstance(); }` . Where `wController` is instance variable within the class where `fullAction` method is defined.